# C++ function slash operator lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

in fact I don't know how to be very precise.

Today, I browsed the following page:

http://siliconframework.org/docs/hello_world.html

I found the following syntax:

```
GET / _hello = [] () { return D(_message = "Hello world."); }
```

I found "GET" can be a function by lambda expression, but I cannot figure out what does "/" and "_hello" mean here, and how they connect to something meaningful.

Also, what is that "_message = "?

BTW, my primary C++ knowledge is before C++11.

I googled quite a bit.

Could any one kindly give an explanation?

Comment: `D` is explained on that page. The / is just the library making the code look closer to what it resembles.

Comment: That looks like an EDSL that uses operator overloading extensively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This library uses what is known as an embedded Domain Specific Language, where it warps C++ and preprocessor syntax in ways that allow a seemingly different language to be just another part of a C++ program.

In short, magic.

The first bit of magic lies in:

```
iod_define_symbol(hello)
```

which is a macro that generates the identifier `_hello` of type `_hello_t`.

It also creates a `_hello_t` type which inherites from a CRTP helper called `iod::symbol<_hello_t>`.

`_hello_t` overrides various operators (including `operator=` and `operator/`) in ways that they don't do what you'd normally expect C++ objects to behave.

```
GET / _hello = [] () { return D(_message = "Hello world."); }
```

so this calls

```
operator=(
  operator/( GET, _hello ),
  /* lambda_goes_here */
);
```

similarly in the lambda:

```
D(_message = "Hello world.");
```

is

```
D( operator=(_message, "Hello world.") );
```

`operator/` and `operator=` can do *nearly anything*.

In the `D` case, `=` doesn't do any assigning -- instead, it builds a structure that basically says "the field called `"message"` is assigned the value `"Hello world."`.

`_message` knows it is called `"message"` because it was generated by a macro `iod_define_symbol(message)` where they took the string `message` and stored it with the type `_message_t`, and created the variable `_message` which is an instance of that type.

`D` takes an number of such key/value pairs and bundles them together.

The lambda returns this bundle.

So `[] () { return D(_message = "Hello world."); }` is a lambda that returns a bundle of key-value pair attachments, written in a strange way.

We then invoke `operator=` with `GET/_hello` on the left hand side.

`GET` is another global object with `operator/` overloaded on it.  I haven't tracked it down.  Suppose it is of type `iod::get_t` (I made up that name: again, I haven't looked up what type it is, and it doesn't really matter)

Then `iod::get_t::operator/(iod::symbol<T> const&)` is overloaded to generate yet another helper type.  This type gets the `T`'s name (in this case `"hello"`), and waits for it to be assigned to by a lambda.

When assigned to, it doesn't do what you expect.  Instead, it goes off and builds an association between `"hello"` and invoking that lambda, where that lambda is expected to return a set of key-value pairs generated by `D`.

We then pass one or more such associations to `http_api`, which gathers up those bundles and builds the data required to run a web server with those queries and those responses, possibly including flags saying "I am going to be an http server".

`sl::mhd_json_serve` then takes that data, and a port number, and actually runs a web server.

All of this is a bunch of layers of abstraction to make some reflection easier.  The structures generated both have C++ identifiers, and similar strings.  The similar strings are exposed in them, and when the json serialization (or deserialization) code is generated, those strings are used to read/write the json values.

The macros merely exist to make writing the boilerplate easier.

Techniques that might be helpful to read on further include "expression templates", "reflection", "CRTP", embedded "Domain Specific Language"s if you want to learn about what is going on here.

Some of the above contains minor "lies told to children" -- in particular, the operator syntax doesn't work quite like I implied.  (`a/b` is not equivalent to `operator/(a,b)`, in that the second won't call member operator `/`.  Understanding that they are *just functions* is what I intend, not that the syntax is the same.)

@mattheiuG (the author of this framework) has shared [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/MatthieuGarrigues/high-per?qid=e6077f33-8af5-4c16-867f-b3879a8a0174&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1#) in a comment below this post that further explains `D` and the `_message` tokens and the framework.

Comment: Plus 1 for the detailed explanation and it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You can read more about symbols and how D(...) builds objects in these slides : http://www.slideshare.net/MatthieuGarrigues/high-per?qid=e6077f33-8af5-4c16-867f-b3879a8a0174&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1# . There is also a short overview of the silicon framework.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that this is an awesome answer and I learned a lot by reading it!

Comment: @matt to bad we do not have `operator""<char...>` that works with quote delimited strings.

Answer (score 7):

It's not standard C++ syntax, it's framework specific instead. The elements prefixed with an underscore (`_hello`, `_message` etc) are used with a symbol definition generator that runs and creates the necessary definitions prior to compilation.

There's some more information on it on the end of this page: http://siliconframework.org/docs/symbols.html. `Qt` does a similar thing with its `moc` tool.

Comment: what's *not standard* about this syntax ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki you need to use a precompiler to generate the underscore-prefixed symbols.

Comment: but `GET / _hello = [] () { return D(_message = "Hello world."); }` itself is feasible in C++

Comment: @mcarton you never need a precompiler to generate any symbols (well, at least not these).  The precompiler can only generate code which the compiler then consumes: if you typed that code in yourself, the result would be the same.

Comment: Indeed, there is a small utility that finds the _xxx symbols and declares them for you. But it is definitely something that you can do by hand but not really fun to write : https://github.com/matt-42/silicon/blob/master/silicon/symbols.hh